# How to store and display chemical formula like (C8H9NO2) from database in php

Tags: php, database

How to store chemical formula like (C8H9NO2) in database in php.
then display chemical formula like (C8H9NO2) in php
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8V0cX.jpg)

Comment: Muhammad, did I answer your question correctly? You should probably mark it as the correct answer so other people can benefit from it.

Comment: Yes, your answer is correctly. thanks

Comment: One more question! follow this link and answer plz              https://stackoverflow.com/q/61565028/13452292

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61564629/13452292

Comment: In that case, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the check mark on the left side of the answer to close this question and answered. People with a similar issue will find the answer more easily if you do so.

Comment: The question you linked me to already has a correct answer in my eyes.

Comment: One more question! follow this link and answer plz https://stackoverflow.com/q/61565028/13452292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it locally, and I think this is what you're looking for:

```
preg_replace('/(\d+)/i', '<sup>$1</sup>', 'C8H9NO2')
// returns "C<sup>8</sup>H<sup>9</sup>NO<sup>2</sup>"
```

You can store this HTML, which will render each number as superscripts. If you want them as subscripts, replace `sup` with `sub`.

As for storing it to the database, I have to be honest and StackOverflow isn't exactly a tutorial website, but you can create a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` column on a database and just store it there. I think it's best to format the text upon saving so that you don't have to do it every time you render a page for each formula you have. However, that depends on you, maybe you need the raw text. I guess it's fine either way.

---

### EDIT

After seeing the picture again, I noticed that it is different than shown in the question, so it is important to pick `sup` or `sub` accordingly. As it is shown in the question, it should be `sup`; but, according to the example image, you are asking for `sub`. Therefore:

```
preg_replace('/(\d+)/i', '<sub>$1</sub>', 'C8H9NO2')
// returns "C<sub>8</sub>H<sub>9</sub>NO<sub>2</sub>"
```

In your code, this would end up being as follows:

```
<b>Molecular Formula by Element:</b> <?=preg_replace('/(\d+)/i', '<sub>$1</sub>', $row['mole_for_element'])?><br>
```

Comment: Plz answer this question                                                 https://stackoverflow.com/q/62316338/13452292

Comment: Plz answerthis question              https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349888/795106

Comment: Plz slove this problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/68264864/13452292