# how to display and add bullet sign every started new line it is data from database

Tags: php, database

Adults and adolescents aged 12 years and over should take two tablets up to four times a day as needed.

Leave at least four hours between doses. Do not take more than 8 tablets in 24 hours.

Panadol extra soluble tablets should be dissolved in a glass of water before taking.

above all text in one field in database, i display in webpage but all paragraph is beginning its show bullets. how?

this code i write  ( `<b>Direction:</b><?php echo nl2br($row["direction"]);?>`   )

[image]

Comment: Recommend 500mg valium every two hours until bullets start appearing in peripheral vision. If bullets refuse to exit from the database within 48 hours, may need to see a doctor for a stronger perception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the `$row["direction"]` string into separate rows (by newline). Loop over them and create a HTML list. Bullets will automagically appear before each line in a `ul/li` list element.

```
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
... etc ...
</ul>
```

I'm not going to spell out the code for you. Here's the homework that gets you there:

- split with: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- or with: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php
- then use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
- to make: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

Comment: i not understant your answer plz slove question

Comment: I don't understand your question to my answer, please clarify what you can't understand.

Comment: How to use

split with: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
or with: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php
then use: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
to make: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp                                                    in this <b>Direction:</b><?php echo nl2br($row["direction"]);?>

Comment: Get rid of the `nl2br`. Use `explode` instead. Then add bullets to the individual lines. Try something and update your post with results.

Comment: Plz answerthis question              https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349888/795106

Comment: Plz answerthis question              https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349888/795106

Comment: slove this problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/68264864/13452292