# how to save all rows data every row name or equal using laravel

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-5

How to save all rows into database using Laravel?
How to save all rows into database using Laravel?
How to save all rows into database using Laravel?
How to save all rows into database using Laravel?How to save all rows into database using Laravel?How to save all rows into database using Laravel?
How to save all rows into database using Laravel?

if click save button then save all rows:

Form screenshot:
[image]

Form code:

```
<!-- Modal Add Wholesale Price -->
    <div class="container mt-3">
      <!-- The Modal -->
        <!-- <div class="modal fade" id="add-wsp"> -->
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content"  style="width:1100px;margin-left:-300px;">
                  
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Add Wholesale Price</h4>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form action="{{route('auth.commvendordata')}}" method="POST" class="shadow-lg p-4 w-f">
                        @csrf
                        <div class="modal-date">
                            <label>Select Date:&emsp;&emsp;</label>
                            <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="Select Price Date" class="getdate"/>
                            <button type="button" name="loadform" class="btn btn-warning load-form">Load Form</button>
    
                        </div>
                      <div class="data" style="display:none;">
                        <table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
                            <thead class="bg-success">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" class="td-size">CCode</th><th scope="col" class="td-size">CUnits</th><th scope="col" class="td-size">CName</th><th scope="col" class="td-size">Vendor 1</th><th scope="col" class="td-size">Vendor 2</th><th scope="col" class="td-size">Vendor 3</th><th scope="col" class="td-size">Vendor 4</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            
                                <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="ccode[]" class="td-size addrow" onclick="addrow();"></td><td><input type="text" name="cunit[]" class="td-size"></td><td><input type="text" name="cname[]" class="td-size"></td><td><input type="text" name="vendor1[]" class="td-size"></td><td><input type="text" name="vendor2[]" class="td-size"></td><td><input type="text" name="vendor3[]" class="td-size"></td><td><input type="text" name="vendor4[]" class="td-size"></td>
                        </tr>
                            
                        </table>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
    
                    </div>
    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i changed the controller code. but not save data into database
df
adf
ad
s
f
asdf
asdfad
f
f d
fa
Form controller:

```
// Controller Save Community Vendor data
    function commvendordata(Request $request){
    // print_r($request->input());
    $request->validate([
        'date'=>'required',
        'ccode[]'=>'required',
        'cunit[]'=>'required',
        'cname[]'=>'required',
        'vendor1[]'=>'required',
        'vendor2[]'=>'required',
        'vendor3[]'=>'required',
        'vendor4[]'=>'required',
    ]);
    // Insert data into database
    $cvendordata = new commvendordata;
    $cvendordata->date = $request->date;
    $cvendordata->cd_id = $request->ccode;
    $cvendordata->unit_id = $request->cunit;
    $cvendordata->cn_id = $request->cname;
    $cvendordata->vender1 = $request->vendor1;
    $cvendordata->vender2 = $request->vendor2;
    $cvendordata->vender3 = $request->vendor3;
    $cvendordata->vender4 = $request->vendor4;
    $save = $cvendordata->save();
    if($save){
        return back()->with('success','Added to database');
    }else{
        return back()->with('fail','Something Wrong');
    }
}
```

Web route:

```
// Communitedy vender data
Route::post('/auth/admin/commvendordata',[MainController::class,'commvendordata'])->name('auth.commvendordata');
```

d
sf
asdf
f
asdfasdfa fa fsdfad
f
f
sdf
asd
fa
d f

Database table screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO.. what you have tried so far and what error your getting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put an array beside the input's name attribute. Like this:

`<input type="text" name="ccode[]" class="td-size addrow" onclick="addrow();">`

In that way, you can iterate your input requests on the controller.

Comment: its i changed. but add the increase controller code  then  can not save data into database

Comment: send your email id it discuss